# How to re-protect part of a Word Doc with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have a custom template that I built in Word.

I used Content controls for certain fill-able fields and used 'Restrict editing' - 'No changes' with exceptions (the content controls) to protect it.

After the user fills out the content control information, they click a "Reset" button to start over. The code associated with this button is below.
Question is: How do I re-protect the doc with the original protection parameters I put in place?
Thank you for your help!
JP

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    ActiveDocument.Unprotect ("Word")
    Dim oCC As ContentControl

    x = 1

    For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls

        Count = x

        If Count > 0 Then
            oCC.Range.Text = ""
        End If

        x = x + 1

    Next oCC

    ActiveDocument.Protect wdNoProtection, , "Word"

End Sub
```

Comment: Word should remember what's been marked as "editable". But you have to apply the correct Protection type when using the Protect method. As it stands, you're telling Word to NOT protect at the end of the macro.

Comment: Thank you Cindy. I posted my latest effort as I am running out of options! I would think that 'wdAllowOnlyReading' would do the trick, but it is not allowing the user to manipulate the edit-able fields after the macro runs. Any ideas what i'm missing? 
thanks again,

Comment: Can't you just use protection type "Filling in forms"?

Comment: @DanL, No. That doesn't work either. Thank you

Comment: I'm surprised Dan's suggestion doesn't work... Could you please give us exact repro steps for setting up a valid test?

Comment: Have you tried your script without unblocking the protection